# writebytes is not copying the exact values?

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

The codes are pretty long and hence, I think it is better if I dont post all of them here. However, if someone thinks it will help, kindly let me know and I will do that.

So, my codes work as required and I have verified this by using `System.out.println("print what is written");`everywhere in the code.

However, when I used the following command to print my final output to csv, I run into the below mentioned problem:

1. The csv file does not contain the right value at the right place. For example, at times it has 0.1 when instead the print command is showing me that the value calculated was -0.1.
2. The csv file has value '0' when the print command is telling me the value is '3'.

Please find below the part of the code, where I feel problem exists, if you guys need me to share more, kindly let me know.

I have been trying to fix it since hours but I simply cant figure out why this is happening. I will appreciate any help..!!!! Thanks a ton..!!

```
// These codes below are inside the main. 
// multi is the instance of a class, and I have constructed the arrays as shown below

User_solution_generation [] multi = new User_solution_generation[total];
for (int i = 0; i < total ; i++) {
    multi[i] = new User_solution_generation();
}

// I do all the steps that I need to do and then  try to write the data into a csv 
// file with the help of the commands below

String Directory = "details";
DataOutputStream user_details;
try {
    user_details = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream("C:/User_Model/" + Directory + "_potentialuser_" 
            + monte + ".csv")));
    user_details.writeBytes("name" + "," + "time" + "," + "vision" + "," + "skill" 
            + "," + "knowledge" + "," + "gamma" + "," + "mem_payoff" + "," 
            + "weight" + "," + "sign_positive_negative" + "," + "action_taken" 
            + "," + "action_change_yes_no" + "," + "problem_reward" + "," 
            + "part_time_reward" + "," + "update_gamma" + "," + "problem experience" 
            + ","  + "problem_found or not" + "," + "time of problem found" + ","  
            + "problem_indentified" + "," + "total reward @problem found end" + "," 
            + "updated knowledge" + "," + "self or neighbour" + ","+ "user or comp" 
            + "," + "max payoff of the neighbour" + "," + "x coordinate" + "," 
            + "y coordinate" + "," + "action immitated" + "," + "shift of value" 
            + "," + "abs capcity of user" + "," + "solution_threshold"  + "," 
            + "solution_action" + "," + "solution_found" + "," + "\n" );


            for (int i=0; i < total; i++){
            for (int t = 0 ; t < time ; t++){
            user_details.writeBytes( multi[i].user_id + "," + t+ "," + multi[i].vision_user +"," + multi[i].skill_user + "," 
        + multi[i].knowledge_user + "," + multi[i].gamma + "," + multi[i].pay_off[t] + "," + multi[i].weight_user + "," + multi[i].sign_user[t] + "," + 
                        multi[i].take_action[t] + "," + 
        multi[i].action_change_user[t] + "," + multi[i].reward[t] + "," + multi[i].part_reward_sum_user[t] + "," + multi[i].Gamma_count_user[t] + ","  + 
        multi[i].problem_experience + "," + multi[i].problem_found + ","  + multi[i].problem_time_count + "," + multi[i].problem_indentified[t] + "," +
        multi[i].total_reward_user + "," +  multi[i].knowledge_updated_user + "," + multi[i].self_or_neighbour[t] + "," + multi[i].user_or_comp[t] + ","+  
        multi[i].max_payoff[t] + "," + multi[i].x_copy_final + "," + multi[i].y_copy_final + ","+ multi[i].action_final_imitation[t] + "," + multi[i].shift[t] + "," + multi[i].z_abs + "," + multi[i].solution_threshold + "," + multi[i].user_solution_action + "," + multi[i].solution_found + "," +
        "\n" );
                }
        }

        //Close the output stream
            user_details.close();
        }
            catch(IOException e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Did you debug this? I dont think the issue is related to the write but to the business logic that calculates such numbers. In which column of the csv are you seeing this? Does it happen always or from time to time?

Comment: It happens from time to time, it is random. I cant predict where does it happen. And, I did debug the previous part of the code where these values are calculated. However, unfortunately I really dont know how to debug this stuff inside the try block. If you know, kindly do let me know. Many thanks..!!

Comment: The thing is: You are using writeBytes to write an String into the OutputStream. You are building that String yourself by concatenating a lot of values and separators. If you see a wrong value in a particular column of your csv then it would be really weird that it's linked to writeBytes (because the whole string isn't messed up, just a single part of it). So I would suspect that the error is not there, but before that.

Comment: Alright, I see your point. However, just to be sure, is it possible to find if writeBytes is causing the problem or not ???

Comment: @Claudio, I wanted to thank for the advise: the error is before that :)       It took me a whole day but I found the error. I had stored a value as a double and at the end was trying to print its value for the entire time period. However, as it was being recalculated at every time period, the printed csv was not what I was expecting. Thanks once again..!!